# How to send arrays / objects to Firebase Realtime Database without them being formatted incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When sending an array to Firebase Realtime Database, I find that it always formats it like a number and not an array.

[image]

Im using Firebase Realtime Database with Node.js to send the array.

This is the portion that sends the array **if it does not exist**

```js
admin.database().ref(`BasicUserData/${msg.author.id}`).set({
    userId: msg.author.id,
    lastUser: msg.author.tag,
    pastUsers: [msg.author.tag], // HERE
    lastAvatar: avatarUrl,
    pastAvatars: [avatarUrl], // HERE
    lastDiscrim: msg.author.discriminator,
    pastDiscrims: [msg.author.discriminator], // HERE
    userCreated: msg.author.createdAt.toDateString()
});
```

Here is the entire Discord.js command plus some variables filled in for context:

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebase = require("firebase");
const serviceAccount = require("(REMOVED).json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://(REMOVED).firebaseio.com"
});

{ ... }

bot.on('message', msg => { // Discord.JS

{ ... }

// !updateUser
case `updateuser`: {
    try {
        let avatarUrl = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${msg.author.id}/${msg.author.avatar}.png`;
        admin.database().ref(`BasicUserData/${msg.author.id}`).on("value", (val) => {
            if (val.hasChild("lastUser")) {
                var data = val.val();
                var pastUsernames = data.pastUsers;
                var pastAvatarURLS = data.pastAvatars;
                var pastDiscriminators = data.pastDiscrims;
                console.info(pastUsernames);
                admin.database().ref(`BasicUserData/${msg.author.id}`).set({
                    userId: msg.author.id,
                    lastUser: msg.author.tag,
                    pastUsers: pastUsernames.push(msg.author.tag),
                    lastAvatar: avatarUrl,
                    pastAvatars: pastAvatarURLS.push(avatarUrl),
                    lastDiscrim: msg.author.discriminator,
                    pastDiscrims: pastDiscriminators.push(msg.author.discriminator),
                    userCreated: msg.author.createdAt.toDateString()
                });
            } else {
                admin.database().ref(`BasicUserData/${msg.author.id}`).set({
                    userId: msg.author.id,
                    lastUser: msg.author.tag,
                    pastUsers: [msg.author.tag],
                    lastAvatar: avatarUrl,
                    pastAvatars: [avatarUrl],
                    lastDiscrim: msg.author.discriminator,
                    pastDiscrims: [msg.author.discriminator],
                    userCreated: msg.author.createdAt.toDateString()
                });
            }
        });
        const dataEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#f4be25')
            .setTitle(`Saving ${msg.author.tag.split("#")[0]}`)
            .addField('Saving Discriminator', msg.author.discriminator, true)
            .addField('Saving Username', `${msg.author.tag}`, true)
            .addField('Saving Creation Date', msg.author.createdAt.toDateString(), true)
            .setThumbnail(avatarUrl);
        msg.channel.send(dataEmbed);
    } catch (e) {
        msg.channel.send(`${e}`);
    }
    break;
}
```

**If anyone could help me out, I would appreciate it.**

Comment: "I'm also having trouble... where this code says that .push() is not a function, even though I never actually ran the code. Its just assuming that the variable isn't an array... so .push() cant work? I have no idea." The computer does not assume anything. **You** assume the variable is an array, but it is not. You need to debug your code to find out why your assumption isn't true.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single issue per post.  Unexpected values being written sounds like a completely different issue than push() not working.  Narrow this down to a single issue and you're more likely to receive a response.

Comment: After debugging, if you still need help, please post the entire error message.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Its fine, I removed that bit of the question. Im more worried about why my arrays are being sent as a number..

Comment: @DougStevenson I apologize, I didnt actually realize I sent two issues until afterwards. I removed the portion about the push method. I can debug that later myself

Comment: What exactly do you expect the database to contain?  We can't see the values of the variables, so it's hard to imagine what you want to happen here.  Try also use hard coded values instead of variables to see what happens.

Comment: @DougStevenson If you look in the javascript snippet I specified, and see the comments that show "// HERE" they show what Im saving.

its just strings. I need to upload a default string. Then, if it exists, add another string to the array and update it on the database

Comment: I see your comments, but I don't know what's in the variables, or what you expect the database to contain after the update completes.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just said it. Strings. I will copy paste it again: I need to upload a default string. After running the function again, if it exists, add another string to the array and update it on the database

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.